# Is it possible to run graphql subscriptions on firebase?

Tags: firebase, graphql, google-cloud-functions

I want to use GraphQL subscription with Firebase cloud functions.
In my previous question I described that when I deployed my code to Firebase it threw me `"Could not connect to websocket endpoint."` and I couldn't even connect to it manually,but when running locally everything works like a charm.
After that I went to see if it is possible to run subscriptions with Firebase,but didn't find anything,only for queries and mutations(it works for me too).

The only post I have found is this: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/graphql/comments/aijebt/graphql_on_firebase/
where someone wrote this :

> "No support for GraphQL subscriptions. GraphQL subscriptions rely on a
>   persistent web socket connection. Since functions shutdown during
>   inactivity, persistent web socket connections are impossible to
>   support."

However I don't want to give up here,because it was 6 months ago,and he said it he tried it while it was beta,so I'm hoping it have the support now.

So my question is:

- **Is it possible to run subscriptions on Firebase?**
- **If not what are your
  advise to do real-time stuff on back-end with Firebase?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to some posts firebase-functions has a maximum lifetime of 9 minutes,so the subscriptions won't work.